# Why doesn't change the color of BottomNavigationView?

Tags: android, kotlin

So, my problem is that, when I change the theme in the application, it works well on all the fragments, except in the MainActivity BottomNavigationView.

I think it isn't use the dark theme colors, just use only the light theme colors, and I don't know why.

I tried some solutions from Stackoverflow but I can't figure up what's wrong.

This is my MainActivity

````
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
        android:background="?attr/BottomMenuBackground"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/bnv_tab_item_foreground"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/bnv_tab_item_foreground" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/nav_view"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/mobile_navigation" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>```

This is my style based on attributes

    <resources>
        <!-- Base application theme. -->
        <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
            <item name="colorPrimary">#e0e0e0</item>
            <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#000000</item>
            <item name="colorAccent">#9e9e9e</item>
            <item name="backgroundColor">#eeeeee</item>
            <item name="warningButtonColor">#b71c1c</item>
            <item name="okButtonColor">#2196F3</item>
            <item name="textColor">#000000</item>
            <item name="disabledTextColor">#BDBDBD</item>
            <item name="bottomMenuTextColor">#9e9e9e</item>
            <item name="BottomMenuBackground">#e0e0e0</item>
            <item name="BottomMenuTintColor">#000000</item>
            <item name="BottomMenuCheckedTextColor">#ffffff</item>
            <item name="dividerColor">#000000</item>
        </style>

        <style name="darkTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
            <item name="colorPrimary">#212121</item>
            <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#000000</item>
            <item name="colorAccent">#202020</item>
            <item name="backgroundColor">#101010</item>
            <item name="warningButtonColor">#b71c1c</item>
            <item name="okButtonColor">#2196F3</item>
            <item name="disabledTextColor">#424242</item>
            <item name="textColor">#fafafa</item>
            <item name="bottomMenuTextColor">#424242</item>
            <item name="BottomMenuBackground">#000000</item>
            <item name="BottomMenuTintColor">#dd2c00</item>
            <item name="BottomMenuCheckedTextColor">#dd2c00</item>
            <item name="dividerColor">#dd2c00</item>
        </style>
    </resources>

And finally my selector of checked button

    <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_checked="true" android:color="?attr/BottomMenuCheckedTextColor" />
    <item android:state_checked="false" android:color="?attr/bottomMenuTextColor"/>
</selector>
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use Dark Mode first change theme parent:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar">
  <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
  <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
  <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

If you want to replace the color in the app, you need to create a custom values directory, called values-night.

[image]

And light mode:

```
<color name="colorPrimary">#e0e0e0</color>
<color name="colorPrimaryDark">#000000</color>
<color name="colorAccent">#9e9e9e</color>
```

Dark mode:

```
<color name="colorPrimary">#212121</color>
<color name="colorPrimaryDark">#000000</color>
<color name="colorAccent">#202020</color>
```

Comment: Thanks, It helped me, but insteresting, because in my previous app which was made in java, my version worked, but it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

Just change your BottomNavigationView `android:background="?attr/BottomMenuBackground"` to `app:itemBackground="?attr/BottomMenuBackground"`