# Proper theme attribute for AppBar icons

Tags: android, material-design, android-theme, android-appbarlayout, android-dark-theme

I have vector icons in my `AppBar`. How do I ensure they get the correct color depending on the theme?

My application uses `Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar` with custom `colorPrimary` and `colorSecondary`.

Should the icons look like so:

```xml
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:tint="?attr/colorOnSurface">
    <path android:fillColor="#FFFFFF" android:pathData="..." />
</vector>
```

or should they use `colorControlNormal`?

```xml
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:tint="?attr/colorControlNormal">
    <path android:fillColor="#FFFFFF" android:pathData="..." />
</vector>
```

or `colorOnPrimarySurface`? (This one makes it always white)

```xml
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:tint="?attr/colorOnPrimarySurface">
    <path android:fillColor="#FFFFFF" android:pathData="..." />
</vector>
```

or should the color be in the `path`?

```xml
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <path android:fillColor="?attr/colorControlNormal (colorOnSurface)" android:pathData="..." />
</vector>
```

or should the color not be set here, but straight in the layout?

```xml
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <path android:fillColor="#FFFFFF" android:pathData="..." />
</vector>

<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:foregroundTint="?attr/colorControlNormal" (colorOnSurface)
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.ActionBar"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.Light">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize" />

</com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
```

Comment: You can look this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61099883/8956604) for Dark-Theme

Comment: that doesn't answer my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I think I found the answer

It should be `colorControlNormal`

> In menu/navigation icons:
>
> ```
> <vector
>     ...
>     android:tint="?attr/colorControlNormal">
>     ...
> </vector>
> ```

Source: https://material.io/develop/android/components/top-app-bars/#regular-top-app-bar